# remix.run loaderfunction vs getserversideprops

Tags: remix.run

i Can't undestand how I can replace getserversideprops in remix.run.
If I use loaderFunction in external components it will not work.

I have a bounch of serverside fetching functions that i need to call when the page is loaded, but using loaderfunction will return unknown type of the object fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "external components it will not work," but you can now infer the loader function in useLoaderData(): https://github.com/remix-run/remix/pull/3276

Example:

```ts
const loader = (args: LoaderArgs)=>{ ... }

function App(){
  const data  = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between getserversideprops and the loader function is the way props are handled in the component.

In Next.js you return a props structure that is the argument of the component, but in Remix, that is done through the the useLoaderData hook https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#useloaderdata

The loader function returns a response to the client. It's an HTTP Response from the server to the client. https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#http-helpers

If you need to call multiple functions in your loader, you can, but remember they run on the server, not on the client so the data should be present in the server.